# Kernel processor power - Event ID 37

Tags: windows-7, cpu, kernel, event-log

> History: 
>   Recently installed Window 7 Home OEM premium, with ubuntu as dual boot on DELL Latitude 3540.

---

In addition to [problem1](https://superuser.com/questions/1188274/processor-core-issue-whea-logger) in Windows7 & [problem2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892029/ubuntu-hangs-need-hard-reboot) in ubuntu,

below is the new problem on my windows7 laptop,

### [image]

### [image]

### [image]

**Question:**

How to resolve this *Event ID 37* problem?

Comment: Have you overclocked?

Comment: @DavidPostill  Am not sure what overclock mean? I did not unscrew my laptop any time before

Comment: Fiddled with any settings to make your processor run faster

Comment: @DavidPostill No I did not. Would u like to confirm any settings?

Comment: Not at this time.

Comment: FWIW, I see this event logged all the time on otherwise perfectly normal systems operating with default settings.

Comment: Than you so much

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things could cause this issue. If its not overclocking then check this stuff out then:

1. Check if there's a bios update you can do first. See if that fixes the issue. but make a backup of it just in case.
2. check to see if the Intel(R) SpeedStep Technology is installed on windows or enabled in the bios
3. In Windows, check your Power Options. Make sure that your Power Scheme is set to High Performance, and check that every option is set to “Always On”.
4. Make sure that your power settings are set to maximum in your bios setting

could be anything related to power or EFI acpi issue

Comment: What about problem1 and problem2 mentioned in query? They are yet to be solved. Do u relate those problems?

Comment: Hard to say. Could be related but I'd rather go with 1 problem at a time. can't really say much about problem2 on linux but problem 1 could be related to hardware issues like overheating, cpu temp or any type of over temperature. In other words, verify your hardware temperature like cpu and air flow.